# Как данному прелодеру добавить проценты и линию загрузки

Tags: javascript

Есть прелодер

```js
window.onload = function() {
        let preloader = document.getElementById('preloader');
        preloader.classList.add('hide-preloader');
        setInterval(function() {
              preloader.classList.add('preloader-hidden');
        }, 999);
        }
```

```css
#preloader.hide-preloader {
    animation: hidePreloader 1s;
    }

#preloader.preloader-hidden {
    display: none;
}

@keyframes hidePreloader {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
  50{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
}
#preloader {
  z-index:99999999;
        min-height: calc(106vh - 50px);
    background: #0e1e6c;
    position:absolut;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id='preloader'>
        <img src="https://www.site.ru/laodi.gif" alt="preloader">
    </div>
```

Как сделать чтобы была полоса загрузки с процентами?

Comment: Пожалуйста переместите свой минимальный запускаемый код в Code Snippet и добавьте CSS

Comment: @EzioMercer сделал

Comment: Добавьте `}` в конец JS, а то консоль ругается ибо вы не закрыли функцию

Comment: @EzioMercer добавил, спасибо

Comment: Теперь расскажите, что именно вы ждёте? Загрузку фотографий? Или ответа сервера? Или просто надо подождать некоторое время? Или просто стили вам нужны? Опишите это всё подробно в своём вопросе, пожалуйста, чтобы другие могли точнее понять суть вопроса и быстрее помочь. Так же не забудьте добавить то что вы уже пробовали. Благодарю за понимание!

Comment: @EzioMercer Спасибо за замечание, но в вопросе в конце у меня написано "Как сделать чтобы была полоса загрузки с процентами?"

Comment: Я понял, но проценты от чего? Вам просто надо чтобы вам дали дизайн такой полоски, где вы сами будете менять числа? Или вам хочется уметь считать процент прогресса какого-то процесса? Потому и говорю, опишите более подробно свою задачу

Comment: @EzioMercer если перейти на основной домен, `avia-avia.ru` вбить данные в поисковую форму, нажать кнопку поиск, запускается данный прелодер, но время и количество его прокруток всегда разная, как я понял зависит от того загрузилась ли страница полностью или нет (но могу ошибаться). Проценты от оставшегося времени до окончания повторных загрузок прелоадера, думаю так.